# Prove or disprove that such a function exists

Tags: calculus

Does there exist a function that is not constant, differentiable on $[-1,1]$ such that $\ f'(x) = 0\ $ for all $x$ not equal to zero?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @spencer does such a function exist?

Comment: This is the closest thing that I know, but it doesn't fit your requirements. The derivative for this function is only zero "almost everywhere" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: The short answer to your question is "no". The function $f$ will be constant on the intervals $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$; continuity of $f$ will require these constant values be the same. Is there some context which makes you think such a function would exist?

Comment: No. Mean value theorem implies that the function is constant in $[\varepsilon,1]$ and $[-1,-\varepsilon]$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Continuity at $x=0$ gives the rest.

Comment: @Spencer it was a question I saw on a sample exam and thought it was interesting. Ps my name is Spencer too

Comment: Proof would look like this: Continuity and f being non-constant implies there exists $a  \neq 0 \in R \ $ such that $f'(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: $$f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, with the given conditions $f$ must be constant and thus $f'(0)=0$ as well.

Since the function is differentiable on $[-1;1]$, it is continuous on that interval. It's not hard to see that $\forall \epsilon > 0: f$ is constant on $[-1;-\epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon;1]$.
This means that arbitrarily close to $0$, the function takes these two constants as its value. Let's call them $a$ and $b$ respectively.

If we take a sequence on $[-1,0)$ converging to $0$ and look at its values by the function $f$, we can conclude that $f(0)=a$ due to continuity. Similarly, by taking a sequence on $(0,1]$ converging to $0$ we can conclude that $f(0)=b$. 
Hence $a=b$ and $f$ is constant on $[-1;1]$.

Similar argument works with any finite number of places where $f'= 0$ isn't required.

Comment: Thanks for responding, however it's not clear to me whether you're arguing the answer is true or false

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is "no". The function $f$ will be constant on the intervals $[−1,0)$ and $(0,1]$; continuity of $f$ will require these constant values be the same.

Some students may be concerned that maybe $f'(0)$ could be some large rate of change that would make a significant difference. It turns out that the contribution to the change in a function from the derivative at a single point in the interval is completely negligible.

Cantor's Function is an interesting example of a function whose derivative is $0$ "almost everywhere", but it is not constant.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Answer (score 1):

To prove $f(0)=f(1)$ we have by mean value theorem there is $c\in (0, 1)$ so that $\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{0-1}=f'(c)=0\implies f(0)=f(1)$,  similarly,  $f(0)=f(-1)$
To show,  $f$ is constant on $[-1, 0]$ choose $c_1\in (-1, 0)$ again applying mean value theorem we will get $f(c_1)=f(-1)$ and hence,  $f(c_1)=f(0)$,  similarly choosing $ c_2\in (0, 1)$ we will obtain $f(c_2)=f(0)$.  So the function is constant having value $f(0)$ at every point.